# Regex expression for password validation

Tags: regex

I'm trying to develop a regular expression for validating a password which should meet following criteria

- should have at least one Uppercase letter,
- should have at least one Lowercase letter,
- should have at least one Special character,
- should have at least one digit,
- must be minimum 6 characters long.

I have developed a expression for that:

```
password_pattern=/^(?=.*[0-9]) (?=.*[!@#$%^&*]) (?=.*[a-z]) (?=.*[A-Z]) {6} $/
```

However it is not working as I intended. What am I going wrong?

I'm new to regular expressions, so I'd appreciate an explanation rather than a 'use this' sort of answer, please explain.

Comment: Do NOT limit what password people may use. [link](http://xkcd.com/936/)

Comment: well he's giving it a lower limit, which is actually a pretty sane thing to do

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a single dot before the `{6}`, and you've added spaces, which you shouldn't have:

```
password_pattern=/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6}$/
```